# Application of fundamental Galois theorem

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose that I have K a galois extension of L such that $G=\text{Gal}(K/L) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} $.

Im am trying to find the number of intermediate fields $E=K^{H}$ such that $[K:E]=4$.

What I know so far: 
$[K:E]=|H|=4$, where $H$ are subgroups of $G$.
$[E:L]=[G:H]=6$.

I have been told I need to find the number of subgroups of $G$ with six elements, but I'm not sure why.

Help, anyone?

Comment: It may help if you think of $G$ as $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Lubin how so? Can you give me more details

Comment: Well, you’re looking for subgroups of $G$ of order $4$ (not $6$), and in the alternative presentation, you can see that the $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$-factor plays no role, so you can just pretend that you’re talking about $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$.

Comment: why are we looking for the subgroups of order 4 instead of order 6?

Comment: You’re looking for the upper layer to be of degree four, right?  I mean, you’re talking about $L\subset E\subset K$ with $[K:E]=4$. So the subgroup of $G$ that you want is of order four.

Comment: This is what I thought, too. But then here is what the solution of the exercise states:  By the fundamental theorem, we need to find the number of subgroups $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times  \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ with six elements.  There are three:  $<(0,2)>,  <(1,2)>$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times <4>$. Is that solution wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57394/discussion-between-lubin-and-usere5225321).